# TypeScript not providing function name

Tags: javascript, reflection, typescript

I have some typescript code, and I'm doing some metaprogramming where I need to be able to access `instance.func.name`, however TypeScript omits the function name in the compiled JS.

TypeScript:

```
class ClassName {
    // ... 
    func(): ReturnType {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Compiled JavaScript:

```
// ...
ClassName.prototype.func = function () {
    // ... 
};
```

Desired JavaScript:

```
ClassName.prototype.func = function func() {
    // ...                          ^^^^
};
```

Is there a compiler option I'm missing, or a keyword I can use in TypeScript to accomplish this?

Answer (score 13):

*A* solution, once which I will not be marking as accepted, because it doesn't provide the `name` property, but does work with any other identifier is as follows:

```
function named(target: any, key: string) {
    target[key].functionName = key;
}

class ClassName {
    // ... 
    @named
    func(): ReturnType {
         // ...
    }
}
```

Then access `instance.func.functionName`.

Comment: pretty clever solution

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to use TypeScript decorators because `function.name` is [readonly property](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=278).

There is a [hacky way](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20ClassName%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%20%0A%20%20%20%20public%20func%20%3D%20function%20test()%20%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09public%20func2()%20%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20instance%20%3D%20new%20ClassName()%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(%22RESULT%22%2C%20instance.func%5B'name'%5D)%3B):

```
class ClassName {
    // ... 
    public func = function test() {

    }

    public func2() {

    }
}

let instance = new ClassName();

console.log("RESULT", instance.func['name']);
```

but it is not exactly what you ask for (i.e. notice the missing prototype in the function declaration).

**Edit:** TypeScript compiler does not write the function name because there is no handling for `SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration` in [emitter.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/emitter.ts#L4671):

```
function shouldEmitFunctionName(node: FunctionLikeDeclaration) {
    if (node.kind === SyntaxKind.FunctionExpression) {
        // Emit name if one is present
        return !!node.name;
    }
    if (node.kind === SyntaxKind.FunctionDeclaration) {
        // Emit name if one is present, or emit generated name in down-level case (for export default case)
        return !!node.name || languageVersion < ScriptTarget.ES6;
    }
}
```

If you want to get your hands dirty, then you can update `./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js` file. Just add the last condition:

```
function shouldEmitFunctionName(node) {
    if (node.kind === 173 /* FunctionExpression */) {
        // Emit name if one is present
        return !!node.name;
    }
    if (node.kind === 213 /* FunctionDeclaration */) {
        // Emit name if one is present, or emit generated name in down-level case (for export default case)
        return !!node.name || languageVersion < 2 /* ES6 */;
    }

    // MODIFIED
    if (node.kind === 143 /* MethodDeclaration */) {                    
        return true;
    }                                                        
}
```

and run this to test the change:

```
$ node ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js hello.ts
```

Comment: Yeah, close but not quite (missing proto). Didn't know TypeScript supported what looks like ES2016 properties though. Handy.

Comment: Nice find, have an upvote. I need to still to stock TypeScript for this project though. :(

Comment: Ask this question here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues. You can link this question, so that they won't need to start from scratch. You will have a definite answer then and act accordingly.

Comment: Done. Will the answer be definitely typed? (I apologize profusely for that joke)