# Get name of function in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was looking for a way to get name of function passing in parameter

```
console.clear();
class A{
   test(){


   }
   testCall(fnc:Function){
     console.log(fnc.name); // i want it display test here not empty
     console.log(fnc);

   }
}

var a=new A();
a.testCall(a.test);
```

you can check this in jsbin
http://jsbin.com/loluhu/edit?js,console

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript
It explains that although there is no real reflection in javascript, you can still use some workarounds but they are not very robust.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get name as String from a Javascript function reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624057/get-name-as-string-from-a-javascript-function-reference)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript not providing function name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647589/typescript-not-providing-function-name)

Answer (score 3):

I found this is a bug in typescript

you can find solution here
[TypeScript not providing function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647589/typescript-not-providing-function-name)

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the Function interface as follows:

```
interface Function {
    name: string;
}

function foo() {}
alert(foo.name);
```

[See here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2076) for a fuller explanation.