# Typescript: how to get function name as string without TS2339 error

Tags: function, typescript, object, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0

I found the following example in the [Function.name documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

```
const o = {
  foo(){}
};
o.foo.name; // "foo";
```

The problem in typescript (typed here):

```
    const o: { foo: () => void } = {
        foo: () => {
        }
    };
    o.foo.name;
```

comes when I want to retrieve 
`o.foo.name`, where I will get an error

> TS2339 (property "name" does not exist)

How can I deal with it, keeping the object typing?
I want to avoid having to cast the property "foo" like `(<any>o.foo).name`

PS: The use case is to keep the typing for further refactoring. For instance the following is safe to be refactored:

```
spyOn(o, (<any>o.foo).name)
```

While this one is not

```
spyOn(o, "foo")
```

PS 2: It seems retrieving function name could be problematic on ts: [Get name of function in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341729/get-name-of-function-in-typescript)

Comment: Your code works fine in the latest Typescript, are you posting the complete code ? maybe there is some other issue ?  Or are you using a previous version of TS

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir typescript 2.3.3 but using "target": "es5" into tsconfig.json, which might be the reason why the property name is considered as missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this code only works for newer versions of Javascript. If you change the target on the typescript compiler settings to `es2015` the problem goes away. If you target `es5` the definitions for that version do not include the `name` property because it might not work on older Javascript runtimes.

If you are ok with targeting es2015, that is ok, if not you should come up with a different solution that works for es5.

If you are targeting an environment that supports this property but you don't yet trust the `es2015` implementation for all features, you could just add the the `Function` interface the missing property. At the top level in one of your files you can redefine the `Function` interface, and this will be merged into the default definition, adding the extra property:

```
interface Function {
  /**
   * Returns the name of the function. Function names are read-only and can not be changed.
   */
  readonly name: string;
}
```

Comment: I was targeting es5 into the tsconfig.json… thank you

Answer (score 2):

Post **ES2015**, this:

```
const o: { foo: () => void } = {
    foo: () => { }
};
console.log(o.foo.name);
```

should work just fine.

Check it in the [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20o%3A%20%7B%20foo%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20foo%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(o.foo.name)%3B%20%0D%0A), and observe the produced JavaScript. You will see the common sections with the `foo` example you mentioned.

Here is the console, nice and clean:

[image]

---

Pre-ES2015, this wouldn't work and I think you would have to cast it, if targeting post-ES2015 is not an option.